# What is this kanji on a Meiji era 2-sen coin?

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

I saw this picture of a Meiji era 2-sen coin in [the 2013 game *Tomb Raider*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_Raider_(2013_video_game)):

- Front:

  [image: Front]
- Back:

  [image: Back]

The front is easily readable, and explained by the caption:

- [大日本]{だいにっぽん}
- [明治]{めいじ}[六年]{ろくねん}
- ２ＳＥＮ

The back is bit more difficult, but I think I got all but one:

- [二銭]{にせん}
- [五十枚]{ごじゅうまい}
- ？[一圓]{いちえん}

What is the one kanji before the 「[一圓]{いちえん}」? Since the rest of it reads legitimate, I believe that's an actual kanji, but it's not very clear.

Comment: Looks like **換** (swap, exchange). See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/換. If you consider that 100銭 gives you 1圓, then 五十枚二銭 exchanges (換) for 一圓.

Comment: @droooze that makes sense. Post an answer, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character looks very much like [**換**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8F%9B), which means to swap or exchange. Since 百錢 exchanges for 一圓, the coin just says 五十枚二銭換一圓 or 50*2銭 coins exchanges for 1圓.

Comment: Thanks. I mistook the radical in it, thought it was , so nothing matched the kanjis I tried drawing.